# Outlook Add-in button appears on ribbon after 20 seconds

Tags: outlook-addin

After updating the manifest.xml to add a second button to the ribbon, it takes about 20 seconds or more after opening the create meeting window for the add-in to appear on the ribbon.
Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Are you sideloading your add-in?

Comment: Yes, I am loading the manifest from OWA.

Comment: So If you are debugging and hosting your Add-in files on localhost, or your own server, it may happen when the ping is low, and your files heavy. Do you have a lot of  graphics in your add-in?